# Как реализовать перевод слова при наведении мышки?

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, api

На сайте https://ororo.tv/ru при наведении мышки на субтитры появляется перевод слова. Как можно сделать нечто похожее без отправки каждый раз API запросов в Yandex Translate или web scraping'а? Важно, чтобы к каждому слову было несколько вариантов перевода.

Comment: создайте свой словарь, если не хотите к чужому API

Answer (score 1):

возьмём видео, в котором 1000 слов, умножим на 3 варианта получим 3000 слов: 1) загрузить к ролику все слова, которые есть только в этом ролике. 2) загружать пачку слов на каждые n минут ролика. В любом случае первично перевести видео как-то надо и это не массив ключ (слово) => значение (перевод) чтобы вы могли словари языков загрузить и переводить.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю как работает этот сервис
1) при наведении мыши ищется слово под мышью и слово выделяется, слово запоминается
2) ищет запрос аяксом к службе перевода
3) при получении перевода показывается перевод в всплывающем окошке

Итого:

"Как можно сделать нечто похожее без отправки каждый раз API запросов в Yandex Translate или web scraping'а?"  - можно весь словарь загружать вместе со страницей и тогда вместо запросов по аяксу можно будет искать в данных на странице. Прикидывая размер словаря - сотни мегабайт, идея эта совсем плохая. Так что ответ, нельзя. Можно если у вас совсем маленький словарь, на пару тысяч слов.

Кстати, возможен вариант, когда 1000 популярных слов сразу грузится на странице. Тогда сначала ищем данные в загруженных данных, а уже потом делаем аякс запрос. 
Еще надо не забыть кешировать запросы которые были сделаны по аякс.